# Returning a string value from a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

In the code below, you see me making an HTTP request. I parse the response and pull out and a "token" (a string) . I want to return that token so that its value is assigned to foo.

```
foo = request.post(
        {
            url: 'http://10.211.55.4/api/2.0/auth/signin',
            body: reqLogin.toString(),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
        },
        function(err, response, body) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                process.exit(1);
            } 
            else {
                parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                    tokencontainer = (result.tsResponse.credentials[0]);
                    token = tokencontainer.$.token;
                    console.log('Logged in, token is ', token);
                    return token;
                });
            }           
        }
    );
```

When I run this code, the object type of foo is Request. Can I somehow cast the whole request to "string" so I don't get the request object assigned to foo? I simply want the "token" value assigned to the variable.

Thanks!

Comment: the X and Y problem,look it up.What's the point of trying to set foo when you know foo can only be set in the future,when the request gets a response? people will answer you but it wont help your case.All subsequent operations in your code will have to be async.

Comment: How does [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) return a promise?

Comment: Learn to use local variable, please. All of `foo`, `tokencontainer`, and `token` are implicitly global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Mikeal's request library, .post() method (or any other) does not return a promise (and even if it did, you wouldn't be able to assign a **value** this way (rather a promise).

So, your options are:

1. move your logic which uses "foo" to a separate function and call it form a callback.
2. wrap .post() in a promise using one of helper libraries (like Q).
3. find anotehr HTTP library which will support promises.

(note: I wrote the code above but have not ran it, so it might not work as-it-is. But it gives you an idea)

**Option 1 could look like:**

```
var logicUsingFoo = function(foo) {
  // do stuff with foo here
};

request.post({...}, function (err, response, body) {
  // ...
  logicUsingFoo(token);
});

// Here, you can't really use foo, because request.post() has not yet
// finished. In Javascript, there's no way to pause program execution.
// You need to either use callbacks, or promises.
```

**Option 2**

Something like (using [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)):

```
var promisePost = function(params) {
    var q = Q.defer();

    request.post(params, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
          q.reject(err);
      } else {
          q.resolve(body);
      }
    };

    return q.promise;
}
```

Then use it:

```
promisePost({url: ..., headers: ...}).then(function (body) {
  // Do stuff with body, obtain token etc.
}, function (err) {
  // Handle error
});
```

**Option 3**

You could use, for instance, [Q-IO](https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io) by Kris Kowal, the same guy who created widely used Q library for promises.

Comment: Thanks. I am using that library. Will go with option #1